# Glassfish redirect

Tags: redirect, glassfish

I have a `Glassifh 2.1` server that has a website running for multiple URLS. For e.g.:

1. www.url1.com
2. www.url2.com
3. www.url3.com

If I enter `www.url1.com`, I want that to redirect to `www.url3.com/com/en/aboutus`.
I've tried adding the following to my `domain.xml`, but it didn't work.

```
<property name="redirect_1" value="from=http:/www.url1.com url-prefix=http://www.url3.com/com/en/aboutus"/>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the "from" attribute requires only a **relative path**, and not a full URL. I don't think that it can be used for what you try to do. Why don't you setup a **simple reverse proxy**, for instance with the apache httpd server? The setup is very simple and will give you a lot of flexibility.